# wordpress code to get attachements from email post

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress default wp_mail.php to fetch email posts. Now I want to get the attachments from the email and publish them with the post. How can I do that without any plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "to fetch email posts" ?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
        the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
    }
}
```